# Web application using Google Calendar API

Tags: python, flask, google-calendar-api

I've created a simple Python/flask website which connects to a Google Calendar via the Google Calendar API. I followed the instructions at https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/python, and it works well...

The whole thing is internal to my company.

I copied the credentials.json and token.json along with my website to an internal device I'm using as a webserver. Again, all works fine.

Except, at some stage, I am under the impression that my credentials will expire, and the web server will need to re-authenticate with my personal google account.

How do I get around this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you researched over on Super User or Server Fault SEs?

Answer (score 2):

The reason your refresh token is expiring is that your app is still in the testing phase. Go to google cloud console under the consent screen and set it to production.  Your tokens will stop expiring.

## web app vs installed app

You should note is the [sample](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/python) you are following states

[image]

and uses the code for an installed application

```
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
```

So by following this example you are not creating a web application you are creating an installed application.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
Unfortunately, I haven't seen any code that is usable for a web app. 

Do you know where I can find content to change this to work for a web app?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are still working on this. I see the ticket is 9 months old but was doing something similar recently so I thought I'd share. Don't use the Oauth2 method that google proposes. Instead:

1. Create a service account on GCS > Create a key and download the **json** (as credentials.json or whatever you want)
2. In the calendar you want to access, go to Settings > Settings for my calendars > Select calendar you want to use > Go to "Access permissions for events" > **+ Add people and groups** > Paste in your service account email > Set permissions to **Make changes to events**
3. Navigate to **Integrate calendar** and copy the calendarId (it will not be **primary** as when using your own account but most likely your email address)
4. Store your **credentials.json** in your project (only for testing)
5. Set an environment variable called **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** to the path of your **credentials.json**. I use an **.env** file and load it using **python-dotenv** but feel free to do as you please. (ex. `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=credentials.json`)
6. Store your `calendarId` somewhere (I stored it in `config.py`)
7. Build whatever process you need starting with `service = build('calendar', 'v3')`. The auth is done in the background using this method.

Here is an example that works fine for me. With a service account, you don't need to go through the OAuth flow.

```py
import config
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from datetime import datetime

def get_calendar_events():
    service = build('calendar', 'v3')
    now = datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'
    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId=config.MAIL_USERNAME, timeMin=now).execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])
    return events
```

Answer (score 0):

Using flask you can design the following scheme.

- You should have a `/auth` endpoint that generates `authorization_url` that you can redirect to perform authorization in Google API.
- You should have a `/callback` endpoint that handles requests when your authorization in Google API is completed. In this callback, you can store your credentials in a flask session.
- Before making events request, you should check whether your stored credentials are still valid. If not, you should call `/auth` again.

In GCP app console, when you create credentials for your app you should choose "web application".
[image]

```py
from flask import Flask, redirect, request, url_for
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"

# this callback URL should match one saved in GCP app console "Authorized redirection URIs" section 
CALLBACK_URL = os.environ.get("CALLBACK_URL") # you can use `url_for('callback')` instead
API_CLIENT_ID = os.environ.get("API_CLIENT_ID")
API_CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ.get("API_CLIENT_SECRET")
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"]

class CalendarClient:
    API_SERVICE = "calendar"
    API_VERSION = "v3"

    def __init__(self, client_id: str, client_secret: str, scopes: Sequence[str]):
        self._client_id = client_id
        self._client_secret = client_secret
        self._scopes = scopes
        self._client_config = {
            "web": {
                "client_id": client_id,
                "client_secret": client_secret,
                "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
                "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
            }
        }

    def get_flow(self, callback_url: str) -> Flow:
        return Flow.from_client_config(
            self._client_config, self._scopes, redirect_uri=callback_url
        )

    def get_auth_url(self, callback_url: str) -> str:
        flow = self.get_flow(callback_url)
        auth_url, _ = flow.authorization_url(
            access_type="offline", include_granted_scopes="true"
        )
        return auth_url

    def get_credentials(self, code: str, callback_url: str) -> Credentials:
        flow = self.get_flow(callback_url)
        flow.fetch_token(code=code)
        return flow.credentials

@app.route("/callback")
def callback():
    credentials = client.get_credentials(
        code=request.args.get("code"),
        callback_url=CALLBACK_URL,
    )
    session["credentials"] = {
        "token": credentials.token,
        "refresh_token": credentials.refresh_token,
        "token_uri": credentials.token_uri,
        "client_id": credentials.client_id,
        "client_secret": credentials.client_secret,
        "scopes": credentials.scopes,
    }
    return credentials.to_json()


@app.route("/auth")
def auth():
    return redirect(client.get_auth_url(CALLBACK_URL))
```

Full codebase: https://github.com/jorzel/flask-google-calendar